# How to register as a Ad Network with Ad mediators like AdMob etc?

Tags: mobile, admob, adwhirl, mopub, millennial-media

I searched a lot but could not find a single documentation on requirements/specs/process for registering as a network with any of the ad mediator liked AdMob etc.

I already know that I would have to create a SDK and a adapter that would communicate with Ad-Mob's SDK but I can't seem to locate any document regarding API standards.

Answer (score 0):

I would contact the Google Devs on the Admob forum
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-admob-ads-sdk